# DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': In Chrome Incognito mode and running in Iframe

Tags: angular, google-chrome, asp.net-core, local-storage, samesite

Can anyone please help me on this issue as I'm getting this same error message on my site when I run it inside iframe of a separate domain in incognito mode only? You can access site from [here](https://www.seguros.es/presupuesto-moto.html).

- No issue on non-incognito mode.
- No issue without iframe as working an individual site
- No issue with those sites that don't use localStorage even running inside iframe or without iframe

Error in console -

"DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document"

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and determined it was because a dependency of our app was throwing an error when trying to access local storage. When the app runs in an iframe in incognito, accessing local storage throws an error. If a dependency does not handle a call to local storage with try / catch, that crashes the app.

The same behavior can be reproduced in the Brave browser, by disabling cookies / local storage.

A good solution would be filing a bug with the library that throws that error (it should be as simple as wrapping that reference in try / catch and ignoring the error).

We also fixed this by adding a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for the local storage object that will do the same thing.

```
<script>
  let storageOrUndefined;

  try {
    storageOrUndefined = window.localStorage;
  } catch (e) {
    storageOrUndefined = undefined;
  }

  const isIframe = window !== window.top;
 
  if (isIframe) {
      const lsProxy = new Proxy(
      {},
      {
        get: (_, prop, __) => (argument) => {
          if (!storageOrUndefined) {
            return null;
          }

          try {
            return storageOrUndefined[prop](argument);
          } catch (e) {
            return null;
          }
        },
      }
    );

    Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", {
      value: lsProxy,
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: false,
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: lifesaver!! I'd been researching all kinds of workarounds but this just works!
I adapted it to create both local and session storage but this got me out of a hole. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Update 4/8/2020**

block third-party cookies

[image]

allow third-party cookies

[image]

From the screenshot above, you can see third-party cookies from

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com
https://cstatic.weborama.fr
https://www.google.com
```

**Removed the direct dependency between page displaying and cookies from these websites.**

---

Follow these steps to unchecked `block third-party cookies` in `Chrome` settings.

This exception is thrown when the "Block third-party cookies and site data" checkbox is set in Content Settings.

To find the setting, open `Chrome` settings, type `"third"` in the search box, check
**`Allow all cookies`** in General settings.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot contact my each and every user and ask them to change this setting. Is there any way to solve this apart from doing anything at user end?

Comment: It's impossible. Reliance on third-party cookies is not an optimal solution. So you need to change on server.

Comment: Still my problem not solved. Still site not working in chrome incognito mode. It works when I allow all cookies from browser settings. Any help with other solution?

Comment: You could check the [sameSite attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute) to allow the thrid party cookies. And the demo to show how to  use [SameSite cookies](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetSameSiteSamples/blob/master/AspNetCore31RazorPages/Startup.cs).